# YII2 - Handle NULL value in gridView- Display a column of foreign keys where some may be NULL

Tags: mysql, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

In brief, I have a table machines, which has a FK pointing to SubCategory.id The relation is correctly setup by Gii. However, the FK column in Machine can be set to NULL as the Action field is not compulsory.

```
 [
    'attribute'=>'machine Sub-category',
    'value' => function ($model) {
    return $model->subCategory->subcat_name;
     },

    ],
```

Above code displays the subcategory name when FK is not NULL. But if FK is NULL, then I get PHP error:

**Trying to get property of non-object**

I understand that error is because of NULL value. ( Because I don't get this error if I add some value instead of NULL)

So my query is - for a FK column that may have NULL values, how do I get them to display in GridView or Detailview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can check if the subcategory is null

```
[
  'attribute'=>'machine Sub-category',
  'value' => function ($model) {
    if (isset($model->subCategory)){
      return $model->subCategory->subcat_name;
      } else {
      return '';
      }
   },
],
```

Comment: If possible, can you please check this(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43062117/yii2-search-with-empty-param-throws-all-records)

Comment: @Rachna  now you hav emore tha 15  rep . so you can also rete as useful an answer